# Undefined control sequence DeclareTCBListing with Tex Live 2019

Tags: tcolorbox, texlive, undefined

I am getting the Undefined control sequence error for `\DeclareTCBListing` command with Tex Live 2019 (Ubuntu 20.04). The same source compiles perfectly fine on Overleaf (Tex Live 2023). Is this some way how to compile it with my Ubuntu as well? 2019 version doesn't seem to be that old.

Minimal source code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{listings}

\DeclareTCBListing{mylisting}{}{}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Error message generated by pdflatex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \DeclareTCBListing
                      {mylisting}{}{}
```

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It works. Actually, it works even when I additionally load the `xparse` library.

Comment: 2019 is old if you use packages like tcolorbox which are actively maintained.

Comment: Yes, TL 2019 is *very* old. Update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems one can convince the code to compile on an ancient texlive system if one uses

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTCBListing{mylisting}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```